# Most Efficient Way to Combine n Number of Pyspark Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, union, aws-glue

I have a particular function I'm needing to optimize with this basic structure:

```
list customer_dfs = []

for customer in customer_list
   df = // Pyspark Transformation Functions

   {10-15 lines of customer specific transformations/aggregations}

   customer_dfs.append(df)


combined_df = spark.createDataFrame([], customer_dfs[0].schema)

for df in customer_dfs:
   combined_df = combined_df.union(df)

return combined_df
```

Even though each of these dataframes are relatively small the performance of this iterative union clearly degrades with each iteration and quickly become untenable.

Is there a faster/more performant way to achieve the same result here? This is something we're looking to execute within the context of an AWS Glue 4.0 Job.

Comment: I assume missing assignment of `combined_df.union(df)` in the for-loop is just a typo. With that, `combined_df` won't be computed until you call an action on it, at which point all legs of the union will be submitted in parallel.

Comment: You’re correct, it is indeed a typo. I’ll modify it, thanks for checking it

Comment: Do you have the option of writing out the `df`s that you're gathering in `customer_dfs` to a temporary storage location?  This way you don't have to keep the result of your transformations in memory, and don't risk excessive deterioration of performance due to memory overflow.

Comment: I would suggest to materialize the intermediate result every Nth iteration by calling a `df.cache().count()` so that the compute graph is not long.

Comment: @ARCrow Yes, I've tried writing the dfs but that is still considerable overhead

Comment: 1. How many DFs and what's the size of each? If you're trying to do something inherently not suited for Spark then you probably won't be able to get around the overhead of Spark (distributed computing). 2. What do you mean assignment is a typo? Without assignment you're simply `union`'ing first and last DF, rest are lost, no?

Comment: I suspect there might be some fundamental flaws in the design but not proficient enough to be sure. We're targeting about 5000 DFs (one for each iteration) and roughly 45-50 rows (max) each. 

I'd made a typo in the code that wasn't assigning so I fixed it. The actual code was assigning correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `reduce` function from the `functools` module along with [`Dataframe.unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html) given that each dataframe is relatively small.
I hope as well the column names are equivalent then:

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Apply reduce using unionByName on the list of customer dataframes
combined_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, customer_dfs)
```

Comment: Isn't this just effectively the same as iteration through the dfs and unioning them together, though? I think I've narrowed down the problem to being not necessarily the end result of the size of the computer df, but the transformations that execute for each iteration.

Comment: The `reduce` function is efficient because it avoids the overhead of creating a new dataframe with each iteration of the `for` loop in a generic sense. Instead, it creates a single dataframe by applying the union operation to all dataframes in the list. But yes, it also depends on the loop that is running prior.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the function like below and keep doing unionbyName to any number of DFs

```
def _agg_dfs(*union_df):
    df = reduce(
        lambda df1, df2: df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True), union_df
    )

# use like below 
output_df = _agg_dfs(df1, df2, df3)
```